Some videos don't work in the next js that I uploaded to firebase storage
porject link https://master--react-next-js-tik-tok-clone.netlify.app/
I upload files to firabase storage and send video links to MongoDB. But the problem is that some videos work fine and some don't. On the site and even when I go to the link on firabase.
const submitVideoToFirebase = async () => {
    const folderRef = ref(storage, `videos/${uuidv4()}`);
    const snapshot = await uploadBytes(folderRef, file);
    const url = await getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref);
    return url
}

link to video that is not showing:
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/react-tik-tok-419113.appspot.com/o/videos%2F27755c0c-6549-4161-8338-5df6effc443a?alt=media&token=d3535fc5-efd0-4f9c-86d6-3b7625e8e218
File type "MP4" (.MP4)
I don't understand what the reason is.

The code you shared looks fine, as does the URL. So the problem is more likely either in the file that you upload or in the code that handles the url that your function returns. Given that the URL shows-but-doesn't-play a video when I open it in a Chrome tab, I'd start with checking if the data you uploaded actually matches the contents of the original file.

MOV" (.MOV) and "MP4" (.mp4) files have no such problems. But "MP4" (.MP4) has a problem. I have no idea what the problem is.

I have now converted the file type from "MP4" (.MP4) to MP4" (.mp4) and everything works.

Thank u. My head hurts, I can't think straight.
